# Use Equals in RouteOnAttribute

Tags: apache-nifi

In RouteOnAttribute I want to send to "unmatched" if merchant contains  "//:"
Will this code work?Could Equals look not at the whole string but only at a part of it?

```
${merchant:equals('://'):not()}
```

Json Body

```
"operation": {
        "type": "A",
        "cardNumber": "123323131223212",
        "tranAmount": 450000,
        "tranType": "2",
        "replyCode": "0",
        "merchant": "hter://req",
        "sourceNumber": "60003234581",
      
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Try regrex like this `${merchant:find('(?i):\/\/')}`. This will give you relation with `merchant` having `://` and then process routed flowfiles to `merchant` relation accordingly